# Update Trigger created successfully but update query results in error

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

So I am trying to create an update trigger for my table. The trigger gets created successfully, no problems there. But when I try to update my table, it gives me an error saying "There is already an object named '#TempTable' in the database". I don't understand why the update query gives this error when the trigger is created successfully??

Here is the code for the trigger which uses temp table:

```
Alter trigger tr_tblPerson_forUpdate
on tblPerson
for Update
as
Begin
    Declare @Id int
    Declare @OldName nvarchar(20), @NewName nvarchar(20)
    Declare @OldEmail nvarchar(20), @NewEmail nvarchar(20)
    Declare @OldGenderId int, @NewGenderId int
    Declare @OldAge int, @NewAge int
    Declare @OldSalary int, @NewSalary int
    Declare @OldCity nvarchar(20), @NewCity nvarchar(20)

    Declare @Auditstring nvarchar (max)
                while(Exists(Select Id from inserted))  
                Begin

                        Select * into #TempTable from INSERTED                          -- Since the logical tables INSERTED & DELETED cannot be 
                                                                                        -- modified manually, we have to create a separate temptable
                                                                                        -- ourselves and store everything from INSERTED table in that
                                                                                        -- table and then use that to form a loop
                        Set @Auditstring = ''                           
                        Select Top 1 @Id = Id, @NewName = Name, @NewEmail = Email,      -- from the inserted table which contains the new data, we are
                        @NewGenderId = GenderId, @NewAge = Age, @NewSalary = Salary,    -- pulling the new data and assigning it to our new data
                        @NewCity = City from #TempTable                                 -- holding variables

                        Select @OldName = Name, @OldEmail = Email, @OldGenderId = GenderId, 
                        @OldAge = Age, @OldSalary = Salary,
                        @OldCity = City from DELETED where Id = @Id

                        Set @Auditstring = 'Person with ID = ' + cast(@Id as nvarchar(5)) + 'changed'

                        if(@NewName!=@OldName)
                        Set @Auditstring = 'Name to ' + @NewName + ','

                        if(@NewEmail!=@OldEmail)
                        Set @Auditstring = 'Email to ' + @NewEmail + ','

                        if(@NewGenderId!=@OldGenderId)
                        Set @Auditstring = 'Gender to ' + cast(@NewGenderId as nvarchar(5))+ ','

                        if(@NewAge!=@OldAge)
                        Set @Auditstring = 'Age to ' + cast(@NewAge as nvarchar(5))+ ','

                        if(@NewSalary!=@OldSalary)
                        Set @Auditstring = 'Salary to ' + cast(@NewSalary as nvarchar(20)) + ','

                        if(@NewCity!=@OldCity)
                        Set @Auditstring = 'City to ' + @NewCity + 'on ' + cast(GetDate() as nvarchar(20))
                        insert into tblAudit values (@Auditstring)
                        Delete from #TempTable where ID = @Id
                End
End
```

And here is the update query that gives an error:

```
update tblPerson set Name = 'Ray', Email = 'ray@ray.com', Age = 32, Salary = 3000, City = 'New York' 
where ID = 1
```

Comment: 1) You tagged the question as MySQL, but the trigger syntax is for ms sql server. Which product do you use? 2) The error is a runtime error, not a compile time one. The code is syntactically correct, therefore you can add the trigger. When it actually runs, it produces an error. You should not really use temporary tables like that.

Comment: Sorry about that.. will remove the tag.

Comment: Many faults here - you're trying to use a temp table to allow you to loop but you're *populating* the table inside the loop. And then your loop condition is not checking that table but `inserted`, so it's an infinite loop. Add to the fact that all of your `if` chains *overwrite* previous results. You can in fact write all of this as a single `insert...select` statement that joins `inserted` and `deleted`.

Comment: Damien_The_Unbeliever: Gracias..!!! this works fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the entire body of your trigger should instead be something like:

```
INSERT INTO tblAudit (/* Some column name here */)
SELECT
    'Person with ID = ' + cast(i.ID as varchar(5)) + ' changed ' +
    CASE WHEN i.Name != d.Name THEN 'Name to ' + i.Name + ', ' ELSE '' END +
    CASE WHEN i.Email != d.Email THEN 'Email to ' + i.Email + ', ' ELSE '' END +
    /* Etc */
FROM
    inserted i
        inner join
    deleted d
        on
          i.ID = d.ID
```

This copes with multiple row updates without needing to loop. No need for temp tables. And the audit information accumulates rather than overwriting each piece